# Android messages app not adding the correct number to group chat

Tags: sms, google-messages

I am running Android version 10 with the latest Messages app. At some point a group chat was created with me and 2 other people, one of whom's phone number is not correct (the incorrect number is the same as the correct number, except the incorrect number does not have an area code attached to it, and as I am in a different area code, it will default to adding the wrong area code). The correct number is stored in my Contacts app, but when I delete the incorrect group chat and try to create a new group chat with those numbers, it adds the incorrect number to the group chat (the one without an area code, even though the Contacts app does have the area code). How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that, is that it looks like it is using the phone number format from your friend's phone.  Get them to make their format more universal. The only phone number you can change is in the Google account in use.